# clr-dropdown menu icons adding a caret

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have my HTML and it looks as below:

```
<div class="col-4 icnContainer">
     <clr-dropdown>
        <button clrDropdownTrigger aria-label="Dropdown demo button">
           <clr-icon shape="ellipsis-vertical"></clr-icon>
        </button>
        <clr-dropdown-menu clrPosition="top-left" *clrIfOpen>
           <div aria-label="Dropdown header Action 1" clrDropdownItem>Action 1</div>
           <div aria-label="Dropdown header Action 2"  clrDropdownItem>Action 2</div>
           <div clrDropdownItem>Link 1</div>
           <div clrDropdownItem>Link 2</div>
        </clr-dropdown-menu>
     </clr-dropdown>
 </div>
```

My output that I get with this kind of setup is shown in the image below:
[image: My output]'

As you can see in the circle, there is an caret added after the Ellipsis. I dont want the caret, I just want the ellipsis like below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve that.
Furthermore, the dropdown is opening inside the containing div as shown below

[image]

How can I get the menu to open outside the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

For positioning the menu you can use one of the following positions:

1. top-right
2. top-left
3. bottom-right
4. bottom-left
5. right-top
6. right-bottom
7. left-top
8. left-bottom

Here is a demo with the `bottom-right` position: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-58030404-dropdown-menu-positioning

I'm not sure where the carot icon is coming from, can you fork and modify the stackblitz to create a reproduction that I can look at?

Comment: Okay let me do that. The issue is not positioning per se.. Its that when the menu opens, it opens inside the containing div. As you can see in the picture it opens to top-right but its inside the div containing the dropdown and not outside where I can access it